# How to get a list of files from FireBase Storage using AngularFire

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire

I've got an Angular 12 app that is using Firebase storage to store some files in a directory.  I implemented the integration with Firebase using the AngularFire solution.  The docs on how to use the AngularFire storage functions don't seem to include how to list all files in a directory.  There are some docs on the Firebase site that speak to this (listAll) but I can't seem to make the code work in Angular with AngularFire.  Code sample from the Firebase site below...

```js
import {
  getStorage,
  ref,
  listAll
} from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();

// Create a reference under which you want to list
const listRef = ref(storage, 'files/uid');

// Find all the prefixes and items.
listAll(listRef)
  .then((res) => {
    res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
      // All the prefixes under listRef.
      // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
    });
    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
      // All the items under listRef.
    });
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  });
```

I've figured out (through the AngularFire documentation) how to get the reference etc. (It's different than in the sample) but I run into problems when I get to the 'listAll' part of the code.

Here's how far I can get in Angular...

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  AngularFireStorage
} from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-openvideo',
  templateUrl: './openvideo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./openvideo.component.css'],
})
export class OpenvideoComponent implements OnInit {
  subscription;
  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {}

  async getVideoList() {
    const directory = 'samplevideos/';
    const listRef = this.storage.ref(directory);
    //Can't make the sample code work here
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngOnDestroy() {}
}
```

The desired state is that I'm retrieving a list of files stored in the targeted directory and then I can do something with that list (I.e. Display the list to the user, allow them to select an item etc.   I feel my struggle here is a combination of documentation gaps between the native Firebase Storage API and the docs that exist on the AngularFire implementation of it, combined with a weak understanding of promises, observables etc.   As a side note I believe I have done the correct configuration (changed to AppModule etc.) to enable the firebase solution in my components and am using it successfully in other components (uploading files for example) so I don't think the issue is one of core configuration of angularfire.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of angular/fire are you using? Also, are you saying you want to display each file in the directory after calling the `listAll` function?

Comment: I'm using version 7 of angular/fire.  Yes that's correct I want to display a list of each file in the directory after calling the listAll function

Comment: What you'll want to do is loop over each file reference returned from listAll and either download the file according to the documentation or get the downloadURL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error I figured out how to make this work in Angular 12.  For those who are interested in getting a list of files in their Firebase storage repository and then populating an array so that you can display the filename and the download link in your Angular component the code I used is found below.  I'll be the first to admit I'm not the greatest coder in the world though so use at your own risk!

```js
//This is where you store the file names and download url's
filelist = []

//This is the function you call (put it in ngOnInit or something of the like) to get the filenames
getFileList() {
  const ref = this.storage.ref('');
  let myurlsubscription = ref.listAll().subscribe((data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
      let name = data.items[i].name;
      let newref = this.storage.ref(data.items[i].name);
      let url = newref.getDownloadURL().subscribe((data) => {
        this.filelist.push({
          name: name,
          videolink: data
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Interested to know how you are able to get this to work. listAll() returns a promise not an Observable https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files#list_all_files